# dependent multi values in setting bundle

Tags: objective-c, settings.bundle, multivalue

I want to use two multi value in setting bundle. Second multi value's values depend on first multi value's chosen value. For example: first one is 'States' and second one is 'Cities'. Every states has different cities. Could i explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a settings bundle. You could put this UI in your app itself, perhaps in a settings screen.

Comment: How can i set multi values' values dynamically? Can u give me a simple  example?

Comment: That's a bit of a vague question; you'll probably need a UITableViewController and need to implement its delegate methods to detect when a row is selected and update the contents of your table. You'll probably want two separate sections; one for states and one for cities.