# rfc 3339 to dd.mm.yyyy format

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, rfc3339

I have a string like that:

```
NSString *string = @"2012-06-14T00:00:00+03:00";
```

I tried this and get "2012-06-14 21:00:00 GMT". But i need "14.06.2012". Is it possible?

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";

NSDate *date;
NSError *error;
[formatter getObjectValue:&date forString:string range:nil error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a second `NSDateFormatter` for the desired format (in this case "dd.MM.yyyy"), and use its `stringFromDate:` methods on your date object to get a string of the desired format. Try adding this code after your existing code.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy";
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556332/dependent-multi-values-in-setting-bundle